# How would I add an action listener to buttons on a loop?

Tags: java, button, javafx

I want it so every time a button is pressed in my 4x4 grid, that it increments `moves` by 1 . This is creating a 4x4 layout of buttons. Each time any of those buttons are pressed, I want `moves` to increment. Basically I'm creating the memory game, where you flip cards over to match each other. I just have to keep count of the total amount of `moves` a player does to solve the puzzle.

```
private int moves = 0;

private GridPane makeGridPane(){
    ConcentrationModel c = new ConcentrationModel();
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col1.setPercentWidth( 50 );

    grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1, col1, col1, col1);
    RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
    row1.setPercentHeight( 50 );
    grid.getRowConstraints().addAll(row1, row1, row1, row1);


    for(int row = 0; row < 4; row ++){
        for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            Button btn = new Button();
            ImageView image = new ImageView(c.getCards().get(0).getImage());
            image.setFitWidth(WIDTH/4);
            image.setFitHeight(HEIGHT/4);
            btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            btn.setGraphic(image);
            grid.add(btn, col, row);


        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Comment: it's just to make my 4x4 board of buttons

Comment: So he needs to develop an event handler to increment moves and link to each of those buttons clicked events?

Comment: @FatFockFrank ...Just ignore my comments. I was reading another question about how to use operators and tabbed over here by accident, then didn't fully reread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple. All you have to do is add this bit of code just before your `grid.add(...)`:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        moves++;
    }
});
```

Or, equivalently, the Java 8 version:

```
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {moves++;});
```

<sup>(I can't currently test this, but it *should* work. If not, lemme know and I'll try to fix it.)</sup>

If you're concerned about memory, [Christian points out below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785302/how-would-i-add-an-action-listener-to-buttons-on-a-loop/29785487?noredirect=1#comment47700952_29785487) that this creates a new instance of `EventHandler` for every button. While this may not be too terrible, it's probably a bad habit to get into. The best way to handle (no pun intended) this is by making an object before your `for` loop:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> eh = new EventHandler<>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        moves++;
    }
};
```

Then, for each of your buttons, instead of the top-most code, you'd simply write:

```
btn.setOnAction(eh);
```

That way, a single `EventHandler` is being created and used to handle all the events. You'll want to use this one if you need to create more than just a few buttons, both because it's faster (doesn't need to allocate memory for each object) and more memory-efficient (...it, uh, doesn't need to allocate the memory for each object). In this case, I think it's pretty trivial, but it's good to know nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a little confused about the `java.awt.event.ActionListener`. Because I'm implementing JavaFX, but isn't `awt` Java Swing?

Comment: @FatFockFrank ...I'm a smart cookie. `AWT` is actually neither, but I need to check how JavaFX does it. Give me a moment to Google that.

Comment: That is bit expensive solution as you would have to create 4x4 instances of EventHandler that will handle the same event. The parent class can implement that function. So if you will increase your buttons to say 16x16 then that will become more expensive.

Comment: Hey thanks for the time. Although this does solve the solution to increment my `moves` variable, I thought it would change my label that I have on my board `labelMoves = new Label(moves + " moves");` `hbox.getChildren().add(labelMoves);`. Once I put this label in an `HBox`, can it not change as I press buttons?

Comment: @FatFockFrank You'll want to ask another question -- while I _could_ give you the answer, what happens when someone Googles "update Label with variable" and they get nothing, despite it being answered right here? So-called "chameleon questions" are discouraged here for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single event handler and reuse it for all the buttons. Since you probably want the buttons to do other things too, I would recommend adding this as an event handler, instead of using the convenience method `setOnAction(...)`:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> incrementMovesHandler = e -> moves++ ;

for(int row = 0; row < 4; row ++){
    for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, incrementMovesHandler);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ...I gotta say, even though that syntax (`= e -> moves++ ;`) is perfectly valid, it _looks_ weird. Very nice solution, though. I hesitate to say it's better than mine because, functionally, they're both equivalent (AFAIK) but still, very clean.

Comment: Just one of those things you get used to... I've been using Java 8 syntax for our in-house apps now for about 18 months (started out with Java 8 ea releases); this syntax started to feel very natural a long time ago. AIUI, they are not quite equivalent under the hood: your code will compile an additional class, for example. (Try it and look at the class files generated.)

Answer (score -2):

You need to implement the `ActionListener` interface in your class.
Then in the `actionPerformed` function, just increment the moves variable.
You just have to call `btn.addActionListener(this);` for each of the button that
you created.

```
public class Sample extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  public Sample ()
  {

  }


  private GridPane makeGridPane()
  {
    ConcentrationModel c = new ConcentrationModel();
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col1.setPercentWidth( 50 );

    grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1, col1, col1, col1);
    RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
    row1.setPercentHeight( 50 );
    grid.getRowConstraints().addAll(row1, row1, row1, row1);


    for(int row = 0; row < 4; row ++){
        for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            Button btn = new Button();
            ImageView image = new ImageView(c.getCards().get(0).getImage());
            image.setFitWidth(WIDTH/4);
            image.setFitHeight(HEIGHT/4);
            btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            btn.setGraphic(image);
            btn.addActionListener(this);
            grid.add(btn, col, row);


        }
    }
    return grid;
  }


  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
    moves++;
  }  

}
```

Comment: This is a JavaFX question.

Comment: I know. I just want to point out that the parent class can implement a Listener interface. The author also did not include so much details.