# Javafx adding ActionListener to button

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, actionlistener

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText("Accepted");
    }
});
```

In the code above we are defining what will happen when we press the button. This is all good but I wanna create new ActionListener and then add it to my button.
Normally in JButton I can just add ActionListener like this:

```
button.addActionListener(someControllerClass.createButtonListener());
```

In code above createButtonListener() returns ActionListener.

My question is: What is the equivalent of JButton addActionListener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is how I should do. Creating the handler:

```
public EventHandler<Event> createSolButtonHandler()
{
    btnSolHandler = new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            System.out.println("Pressed!");
            biddingHelperFrame.getBtnSag().setVisible(false);
        }
    };
    return btnSolHandler;
}
```

Adding Handler to button:

```
btnSol.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, biddingHelperFrameController.createSolButtonHandler());
```

Comment: Why do you want to provide a method (for your explicit stated code example) returning a new EventHandler contrary to the approach in my answer?

Comment: @SSchuette In your answer you can have only one event handler at a time . The OP may need more actions to be fired so he needs multiple action handlers.

Comment: Yep, full ack @GoXR3Plus but that's why asked - the described scenario seemed to be "ok" with the single handler.

Comment: I just post an answer to my own question accourding to your suggestion @SSchuette. It is working perfectly.

Comment: Btw I didnt see your question soryy @SSchuette. I am trying to do MVC pattern. I dont want to mix view class and controller class together, so only controller knows what the button does, not the view class.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to create multiple instances of the same EventHandler by a method like this. Do it as shown in the other answer.

Comment: I don't like putting what button does and buttons definition in time same place. @Clemens

Comment: @MertG Not sure what you're trying to say, but having a `createSolButtonHandler()` like this is obviously nonsense.

Comment: @Clemens I have 2 seperate class 1st one is just the GUI components and the 2nd one is a controller which controls what will buttons do, so when I code 1st class I dont like putting what button does in that class. That is controllers job. I create and determine what will they do at 2nd class and add them to 1st class.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to e.g. reuse an `EventHandler`, define it like described in [JavaFX Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm#BABBHHCJ) as:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> buttonHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Accepted");
        event.consume();
    }
};
```

You can now add your defined `buttonHandler` to the `onAction` of your button via:

```
button.setOnAction(buttonHandler);
```

And citing from the documentation providing the remove option for completeness:

> To remove an event handler that was registered by a convenience method, pass null to the convenience method, for example, `node1.setOnMouseDragged(null).`

Resulting for you in:

```
button.setOnAction(null)
```

The documentation furthermore provides some examples how to add handler for specific events - it's a good read.

Comment: Ty for your answer SSchuette. If I understand you correctly you are saying  I should use eventHandlers instead of actionListeners. Am I right?

Comment: As you're seeming to come from Swing (your JButton statement) you've to keep terminology correspondig to your UI framework. EDIT: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29785487/2061026

Comment: Yeah I just look for eventHandlers and its a bit different, but I solved my problem thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries @MertG - switching the UI framework takes some time. Especially if you're continuously mixing Swing, JavaFX, WPF and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Just the same approach, but easier with lamda expressions:

```
button.setOnAction(event -> buttonSaveClicked());
```