# JavaFX Menu Item name

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I looked online but I couldn't find it. How can I get the name of the clicked menu item when somebody clicks it.I want to change the scene according to the clicked menu item but I don't want to create 8 different methods. If I can get the name of the clicked menu item I can create 1 method that takes that name as a parameter and launches the FXML Loader and changes the scene[image]

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use Menu/Items (should give you an idea of how to do), apply what you learned to your context, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register an inline listener to the MenuItem(s) onAction event in the initialization method.

```
for (MenuItem item : menu.items()) {
item.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        processCategory(item.getText()); // this would do your thing you want to do.
        event.consume();
    });

}
```

Comment: the answer is okay, the comment is plain wrong: event handlers are always notified on the fx thread

Comment: Yeah, I may have been thinking of ListChangeEvents ;)  I haven't touched Javafx in a year.

Answer (score -2):

As is mentioned here: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent&method=getSource

You can do it like:

```
private void handleLabel(MouseEvent event) { 
    Node label = (Node) event.getSource();
    System.out.println("Mouse click on label: " + label.getId());
}
```

Comment: hmm .. and how do you apply that to a menuItem?

Comment: Need to use ActionListener on an Actionable component.

Comment: Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40758244/10802597 i believe there is some kind of setOnMouseClickListener or something like this